# SolidWorks Macro "Copy with Mates"

Tags: vba, solidworks

SolidWorks 2019

We have an assembly consisting of 1) a part and 2) an assembly consiting of 2 parts.

Number 2) is mated to number 1) with 4 mates. We use the built in "Copy with Mates", and change just 1 mate (see image, we change the latter mate). That works very well.

We then try and record the task as a macro, but it does not work. Below is the recorded macro. We have to copy 70 times, so we want to script it, if we can... It seems like the macro does not record all the commands since its only showing "SelectByID2"?

```
Dim swApp As Object

Dim Part As Object
Dim boolstatus As Boolean
Dim longstatus As Long, longwarnings As Long

Sub main()

Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc
Dim myModelView As Object
Set myModelView = Part.ActiveView
myModelView.FrameState = swWindowState_e.swWindowMaximized
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("VG_35_mm_pair-1@B52_with_hub_Assembly_VG_Test_2_MacroTest", "COMPONENT", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("VG_35_mm_pair-1@B52_with_hub_Assembly_VG_Test_2_MacroTest", "COMPONENT", 0, 0, 0, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Spline1@Front_Curve@B52_with_hub_Part_VG_Test_1-1@B52_with_hub_Assembly_VG_Test_2_MacroTest", "EXTSKETCHSEGMENT", -6.26992150606958, 0.775894302170855, -15.7340472890057, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Spline1@Front_Curve@B52_with_hub_Part_VG_Test_1-1@B52_with_hub_Assembly_VG_Test_2_MacroTest", "EXTSKETCHSEGMENT", -6.26992150606958, 0.775894302170855, -15.7340472890057, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("", "FACE", 0.72965560792877, -2.76149537219488, -52.245, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("", "FACE", -0.163628357652359, -0.693217558762202, -1.5, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Spline1@Front_Curve@B52_with_hub_Part_VG_Test_1-1@B52_with_hub_Assembly_VG_Test_2_MacroTest", "EXTSKETCHSEGMENT", -6.26992150606958, 0.775894302170855, -15.7340472890057, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByID2("Spline1@Front_Curve@B52_with_hub_Part_VG_Test_1-1@B52_with_hub_Assembly_VG_Test_2_MacroTest", "EXTSKETCHSEGMENT", -6.26992150606958, 0.775894302170855, -15.7340472890057, True, 0, Nothing, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByRay(0.72965560792877, -2.76149537219488, -52.245, 0.884362037190013, -0.288902374358076, -0.366659522264726, 4.02652481088142E-03, 2, True, 0, 0)
boolstatus = Part.Extension.SelectByRay(-0.163628357652359, -0.693217558762202, -1.5, 0.884362037190013, -0.288902374358076, -0.366659522264726, 4.02652481088142E-03, 2, True, 0, 0)
Part.ClearSelection2 True
boolstatus = Part.EditRebuild3()
End Sub
```

[image: copy with mates]

Answer (score 3):

Not all soldiworks operations can be recorded as a macro. More complicated ones usually can't. If you want to automate it you'll have to do bulk of the work yourself.

I'd suggest first to use API to figure out what kind of mates you'll want to add using the part that was manually set up to be correct : [example](http://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/get_mates_example_vbnet.htm).

And then follow [this](https://help.solidworks.com/2016/english/api/sldworksapi/Add_Component_and_Mate_Example_VBNET.htm) to insert component and add mates.